# Importing a class to another class in python

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python i tried to import a class in another class but it is not working

`Application.py`:

```
class Application:

    def example(self):
        return "i am from Application class"
```

`Main.py`

```
class Main:

    def main():
        application = Application()
        application.example()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main.main()
```

This gives me :

```
File "Main.py", line 11, in <module>
    Main.main()
TypeError: unbound method main() must be called with Main instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: Your code does not import anything and you left out the `self` argument to `main`.  You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to learn the basics of importing.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with importing; you'll get the same error if you remove any mention of `Application`.

Comment: python is not java;  why do you need a class for your main function?

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate your Main class first.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myMain = Main()
    myMain.main()
```

But this will give you another error:

> TypeError: main() takes no arguments (1 given)

There are two ways to fix this. Either make Main.main take one argument:

```
class Main:
    def main(self):
        application = Application()
        application.example()
```

or make Main.main a static method. In which case you don't have to instantiate your Main class:

```
class Main:
    @staticmethod
    def main():
        application = Application()
        application.example()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with importing (Although you don't seem to import `Application` anywhere). The problem is that you use the `main` method like a static method without declaring it to be static.

To solve this, You either need to declare your `main` method as static or create an instance of the `Main` class.

As a static method (add the `@staticmethod` decorator):

```
class Main():

    @staticmethod
    def main():
       ...
```

With an Instance:

```
class Main():

    def main(self):
        ....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myMain = Main() #create an instance
    myMain.main()   #call the function on the instance
```

Also, to import your `Application` class from Application.py, you would just write this:

```
from Application import Application
```